# How to Find MongoDB Documents with the Same Value and Count Them?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, nosql

In MongoDB, I need to use group aggregation (I believe), in order to get the number of documents in a collection with the same value. I need to get these results returned to me from greatest to least, and then get the common value for each result.

Eg.

1. I have a normal query with a range (eg. field "value" > 5). I assume for this I should use the "match" feature when aggregating
2. Get all documents with the same value for the "id" field, that also match the above query parameters
3. Sort the results from most matching values to least
4. Give me the common value of "id" for each result.

Sample documents:

```
    #1. Type: "Like", value: 6, id: 123
    #2. Type: "Like", value: 7, id: 123
    #3. Type: "Like", value: 7, id: 123
    #4. Type: "Like", value: 8, id: 12345
    #5. Type: "Like", value: 7, id: 12345
    #6. Type: "Like", value: 6, id: 1234
    #7. Type: "Like", value: 2, id: 1234
    #7. Type: "Like", value: 2, id: 1234
    #7. Type: "Like", value: 2, id: 1234
```

Expected output (assume I have a limit of 3 documents, and the query asks for only documents with the "value" field > 5):

```
1. id: 123
2. id: 12345
3. id: 1234
```

I expect these in this order, as the id 123 is most popular, and 1234 is least popular, of the documents where the "value" field > 5.

Ideally, I would have a method that would return something like a String[] of the resulting Ids, in order.

Comment: Can you add some sample documents and what you expect the output to look like? Makes it much easier for people to suggest solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.data.aggregate([
    {$match: {value:{$gt:5}}},
    {$group: {'_id':"$id", num:{$sum:1}, avg:{$avg:"$value"}}},
    {$sort:{num:-1}}, { $limit : 50}
])
```

Comment: Why is the documentation for aggregations designed for people that already understand them instead of for beginners? And why does all of stack overflow have the same approach of either A. Not explaining at all, or B. Explaining as though the person already understands all of the concepts and just needs a light refresher?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').aggregate([
    //Only include documents whose field named "value" is greater than 5
    {
        $match: {
            value: { 
                $gt:5 
            } 
        }
    },
    //Using the documents gathered from the $match above, create a new set of 
    // documents grouped by the "id" field, and use the "id" field as the "_id" 
    // for the group. Make a new field called "num" that increments by 1 for 
    // every matching document. Make a new field named "avg" that is the average 
    // of the field named "value".
    {
        $group: {
            '_id' : "$id", 
            num : {
                $sum : 1
            }, 
            avg : {
                $avg : "$value"
            }
        }//end $group
    },
    // -- //
    // Note: you could do another $match here, which would run on the new 
    // documents created by $group.
    // -- //
    //Sort the new documents by the "num" field in descending order
    {
        $sort : { 
            num : -1
        }
    }, 
    //Only return the first 3 of the new documents
    {
        $limit : 3
    }
])
```